# Sort output of s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3

How can I sort the output of an

```
s3cmd ls s3://xxx.yyy.zzz/kkk/
```

based on date?

(This is not duplicate of [How to sort output of "s3cmd ls"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674117/how-to-sort-output-of-s3cmd-ls))

Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just pipe output to sort

```
s3cmd ls s3://xxx.yyy.zzz/kkk/ | sort
```